# Filter AFNetworking response

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

My AFNetworking API response contains a json object "place" which can be "restaurant" or "store". I want to filter the response to add to the location_results array only if the place object contains the keyword "store"

Here is my AFNetworking request

```
  [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations.json" parameters:nil                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
        NSMutableArray *location_results = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (id locationDictionary in response) {
            Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
            [location_results addObject:location]; 
        }
        self.location_results = location_results;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                        }];


}
```

I tried adding this

```
for (id locationDictionary in response) {
    Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
    if([[location objectForKey:@"place"] isEqualToString:@"Store"]) // Added this line
        [location_results addObject:location];

}
```

but I get an error - no visible @interface for 'Location' declares the selector 'objectForKey'

How can I filter this response before `[location_results addObject:location];` ?

Comment: Do you want to use KVC? If yes use `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`. Because `objectForKey:` is method of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks @VitaliyB I think I'm going to stick with objectForKey and use the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to answer my question by adding this line

```
self.location_results = [location_results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                                 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K contains %@)",@"place" ,@"store"]];
```

to

```
  }
        self.location_results = location_results; //replaced this line
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```